# Symfony2 как получить доступ к сервису вне контроллера а в кастомном классе?

Tags: symfony2

Хочу сделать свой кастомный класс для работы с базой.
Не могу получить доктрину отдельно от модели или контроллера.
Поэтому сделал RepositoryDoctrineHelper:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\TrainingBundle\Util;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class RepositoryHelper
{
    private $manager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    public function getRepository($entityName)
    {
        return $this->manager->getRepository($entityName);
    }
}
```

Теперь хочу получить этот класс вне контроллера! Т.е. сервисом его наверное делать смысла ВОООБЩЕ нет, т.к. и сервис вне контроллера непонятно как получать, верно?
Нашел только один костыль и очень плохой выход:

```
global $kernel;
```

Comment: "Т.е. сервисом его наверное делать смысла ВОООБЩЕ нет, т.к. и сервис вне контроллера непонятно как получать, верно?"

Почему вы считаете, что сервисы без контроллера не могут существовать? Именно там он и должен оказаться.
Отдельный вопрос - зачем вам вообще заворачивать доктрину в еще что-то? И что это вообще за ситуация такая, которая происходит не внутри контроллера и не внутри ContainerAwareCommand?

Comment: Я создаю отдельную папку для классов нужных для выполнения однотипных действий, но с разными сущностями.
Эти классы просто напросто не могут быть контроллерами в том плане, что расширяют один интерфейс и должны содержать определенные методы.
Т.е. это отдельная кастомная папка\неймспейс в бандле, 
По-поводу ContainerAwareCommand немного непонятно стало, может проблема в этом и нужно имплементить от ContainerAwareCommand для доступа к контейнеру?

Comment: Кстати, создание и определение статическим методом getContainer у основного класса бандла  - тоже плохая практика?
Чтобы потом делать так:
$container = AcmeTrainingBundle::getContainer(); 
$container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

Comment: Так, с самого начала - что делаете, что нужно получить, каким способом должно запускаться.